# http post setEntity using retrofit

Tags: android, http, post, retrofit

I recently move to Retrofit, I want to replace this httpost set entity using Retrofit. How can i do it.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("childId", childId);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

this is what i was trying to do, but it dosent work,

```
    Observable<Item> getListOfFeed(@Body StringEntity params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally figure out the answer, add a custom TypedJsonString class,

```
public class TypedJsonString extends TypedString {
    public TypedJsonString(String body) {
        super(body);
    }

    @Override public String mimeType() {
        return "application/json";
    }
}
```

convert my json object to TypedJsonString,

```
TypedJsonString typedJsonString = new TypedJsonString(jsonObject.toString());
```

changed the api class as follows,

```
Observable<Item> getListOfFeed(@Body TypedJsonString typedJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send request with `Post` using following code in `Retrofit` inside your API interface

```
public interface MyAPI{
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("rest url")
 Call<Item> loadQuestions(@Field("parameter_name")String order);
}
```

Dont forget to mention `@FormUrlEncoded`, To call this function use this

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("url")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
MyAPI api=retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);
Call<Item> call=api.loadQuestions("pass your data here");
call.enqueue(new Callback<Item>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Item> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.e("response",response.message());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
});
```